# How to list active sessions in Kiwi TCMS?

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I use Kiwi TCMS v12.2 on ubuntu VM running 22.04.2 server edition. I would like to know if there is a way to use manage.py or some other utility within the kiwi_web container to list and kill specific active sessions.

I tried running

```
$ docker exec -it kiwi_web /Kiwi/manage.py help
```

but I haven't seen any command that would let me do it. I have only seen the `print_user_for_session` there, but I could not use it since I could not find the session id for any active session.

Any suggestions?